# Scanner en Java marca que nunca se cerró

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

```
Scanner sc = new scanner(system.in);
```

En el sc marca que nunca se cerró y no me deja compilar o me compila otro proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que no has puesto tu código (sería lo ideal) y tampoco has dicho si te sale algún error y qué dice, la ayuda que puedo ofrecerte es bien limitada.

1. Asegúrate de tener la librería `java.util.Scanner` importada en tu proyecto.
2. Asegúrate de cerrar el Scanner al final de tu código, cuando usas Scanner, siempre debes hacer `sc.close()`. Esto lo indica la [documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), aunque muchas personas no lo hacen, pero, si los jefes lo dicen, por qué no hacerlo?, xDDD. A lo mejor esta puede ser la causa de tu problema.
3. Mencionas que cuando haces clic en Run para ejecutar tu programa a veces te ejecuta otro proyecto, cierto?. Las clases que has ejecutado recientemente en Eclipse se quedan guardadas y a lo mejor una de ellas sigue priorizada para ser ejecutada. Para ejecutar un archivo manualmente, haces lo siguiente: **Clic derecho en el archivo -> RunAs - > Java Application**.

Comment: En los casos como el que estas aclarando al comenzar tu respuesta, se recomienda esperar a que OP mejore su pregunta. En tal caso con un comentario donde se le aclare que falta para contestar su pregunta alcanza.